# Python Selenium: How do I select a value from drop down menu

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing a python selenium script. I wanted to select below class:

```
    <select style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" class="gwt-ListBox project-list">
    <option value="10">Case Notes</option>
```

but got failed:

```
elem  = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//contains[@class=gwt-ListBox.project-list']")
```

Can any one explore please.

Comment: You miss a '  after @class=

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12029/how-do-i-work-with-dropdowns-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: In my scenario I have not any id for<select> class @saurabhbaid

Comment: That was just to give you an Idea on how to select value from drop down. Also class name in your XPATH does not match class name in your HTML code. Cross check that.

Comment: Any one have solution for this? or any other way can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you missed a quote `'` after the `=`. The following will work:

```
elem  = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//contains[@class='gwt-ListBox.dashboard-listbox.project-list']")
```

Hope it worked

Comment: I am getting below error after incorporated your suggestion:-
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[contains(@class, 'gwt-ListBox.dashboard-listbox.project-list')]"}

Comment: Can you try to get the xpath using chrome.

Comment: @Jeril   From HTML snippet his class name is `gwt-ListBox project-list`

Comment: Can you share the link where you are try to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Xpath

```
"//select[@class='gwt-ListBox project-list']"
```